# Unable to set Cookie with httpclient Android

Tags: android, cookies, httpclient

cookies are not being set , below is the code.

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPostRequest = new HttpPost(URL);

CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore(); 
BasicClientCookie cookie = new BasicClientCookie("Name", "value");
cookieStore.addCookie(cookie); 

HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();

localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
httpPostRequest.setEntity(fileentity);

HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpPostRequest,localContext);
```

have also tried

```
httpclient.setCookieStore(cookieStore);
```

but nothing works .

Comment: I use _httpclient.addHeader("Cookie", cookieValue)_ and it works